# "Спустя многие годы(,)...." Нужна ли в этом случае запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Спустя многие годы(,) я встретила его в одном из зданий лечебного профилактория.

Answer (score 6):

**Спустя многие годы** я встретила его в одном из зданий лечебного профилактория.

СПУСТЯ, предлог. кого-что. По прошествии какого-л. времени. С. час двинулись дальше. С. несколько месяцев мы встретились снова.

Обстоятельственный оборот с этим предлогом обычно обособляется, если имеет значение **уточнения:**

Примеры

Быть может, это и позволило мне потом, **спустя многие годы**, без страха входить в кабинет Сталина, сидеть рядом с ним, не ощущая опасности… [Валентин Бережков. Рядом со Сталиным (1971-1998)]

И лишь **спустя многие годы** мы начали постепенно понимать, что это было не совсем так. [Владимир Молчанов, Консуэло Сегура. И дольше века... (1999-2003)]